# python loop dictionary value references updating all values

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, nested

I am having a problem updating values in a dictionary in python. I am trying to update a nested value (either as an int or list) for a single fist level key, but instead i update the values, for all first level keys.

I start by creating the dictionary:

```
kmerdict = {}
innerdict = {'endcover':0, 'coverdict':{}, 'coverholder':[], 'uncovered':0, 'lowstart':0,'totaluncover':0, 'totalbases':0}
for kmer in kmerlist: # build kmerdict
    kmerdict [kmer] = {}
    for chrom in fas:  #open file and read line
        chromnum = chrom[3:-3]
        kmerdict [kmer][chromnum] = innerdict
```

Then i am walking through chromosomes (as plain text files) from a list (fas, not shown), and taking 7mer strings (k=7) as the key. If that key is in a list of keys i am looking for (kmerlist) and trying to use that to reference a single value nested in the dictionary:

```
for chrom in fas:  #open file and read line
    chromnum = chrom[3:-3]
    p = 0  #chromosome position counter
    thisfile = "/var/store/fa/" + chrom
    thischrom = open(thisfile)
    thischrom.readline()
    thisline = thischrom.readline()
    thisline = string.strip(thisline.lower())
    l=0  #line counter
    workline = thisline
    while(thisline):
        if len(workline) > k-1:
            thiskmer = ''
            thiskmer = workline[0:k] #read five bases
            if thiskmer in kmerlist:
                thisuncovered = kmerdict[thiskmer][chromnum]['uncovered']
                thisendcover =  kmerdict[thiskmer][chromnum]['endcover']
                thiscoverholder = kmerdict[thiskmer][chromnum]['coverholder']
                if p >= thisendcover:
                    thisuncovered += (p - thisendcover)
                    thisendcover = ((p+k) + ext)
                    thiscoverholder.append(p)
                elif p < thisendcover:
                    thisendcover = ((p+k) + ext)
                    thiscoverholder.append(p)
            print kmerdict[thiskmer]
            p += 1
            workline = workline[1:]
        else:
            thisline = thischrom.readline()
            thisline = string.strip(thisline.lower())
            workline = workline+thisline
            l+=1
print kmerdict
```

but when i print the dictionary, all "thiskmer" levels are getting updated with the same values. I'm not very good with dictionaries, and i can't see the error of my ways, but they are profound! Can anyone enlighten me?

Hope i've been clear enough. I've been tinkering with this code for too long now :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*confession* -- I haven't spent the time to figure out all of your code -- only the first part.  The first problem you have is in the setup:

```
kmerdict = {}
innerdict = {'endcover':0, 'coverdict':{}, 'coverholder':[], 'uncovered':0, 
             'lowstart':0,'totaluncover':0, 'totalbases':0}
for kmer in kmerlist: # build kmerdict
    kmerdict [kmer] = {}
    for chrom in fas:  #open file and read line
        chromnum = chrom[3:-3]
        kmerdict [kmer][chromnum] = innerdict
```

You create `innerdict` once and then proceed to use **the same dictionary** over an over again.  In other words, every `kmerdict[kmer][chromnum]` refers to the same objects.  Perhaps changing the last line to:

```
kmerdict [kmer][chromnum] = copy.deepcopy(innerdict)
```

would help (with an appropriate import of `copy` at the top of your file)?  Alternatively, you could just move the creation of `innerdict` into the inner loop as pointed out in the comments:

```
def get_inner_dict():
    return {'endcover':0, 'coverdict':{}, 'coverholder':[], 'uncovered':0, 
            'lowstart':0,'totaluncover':0, 'totalbases':0}

kmerdict = {}
for kmer in kmerlist: # build kmerdict
    kmerdict [kmer] = {}
    for chrom in fas:  #open file and read line
        chromnum = chrom[3:-3]
        kmerdict [kmer][chromnum] = get_inner_dict()
```

-- I decided to use a function to make it easier to read :).

Comment: @unutbu -- Yes, that would be a more sensible fix wouldn't it?  shoveled a little too much snow today I guess.

Comment: Awesome! moved innerdict into the inner loop. Pretty obvious i haven't mastered the way python references yet. Good luck with the snow.